# carousel place img not centered but right at smaller screensize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I made a FULL SCREEN slider using carousel bootstrap.
When the screen size get smaller, the background image resized and centered.
I don't want to make it centered when the screen get smaller, but I want to make the background image focus on the right instead.

this is how the background image looks like on normal screen (it's fullscreen slider):
[Normal Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOCTE.jpg)

this is how the background image looks like on smaller screen (still fullscreen):
[Smaller Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS3TT.jpg)

This is what I've done

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {      
  .carousel-inner>.item{
        position: relative;
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item>img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
 <div class="item active">
  <img id="h-1" src="Assets/1.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>C</h1>
      <hr>
      <ul class="descslider">       
     <li>asd</li>
     <li>qwe</li>
     <li>zxcv</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
  <img id="h-2" src="Assets/2.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>C</h1>
      <hr>
      <ul class="descslider">       
     <li>asd</li>
     <li>qwe</li>
     <li>zxcv</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
  <img id="h-3" src="Assets/3.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>C</h1>
      <hr>
      <ul class="descslider">       
     <li>asd</li>
     <li>qwe</li>
     <li>zxcv</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

that thing that I've tried didn't work at all
Pls help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got what you're looking for now, you want it to resizes with the image on the right at a certain breakpoint when the window resizes. Bootstrap has what amounts to float classes `pull-right`, and `pull-left`.

I used jQuery to apply these classes when the viewport size is below 768px, and added some custom CSS as well.

JS:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if($(window).height() > 768) {
        $('img').addClass('pull-right');
        $('.carousel-caption').addClass('pull-left');
    }else{
        $('img').removeClass('pull-right');
        $('.carousel-caption').removeClass('pull-left');
    }
})
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {      
  .carousel-inner >.item > img{
      max-width: 40%;
    }
   .carousel-caption{
      max-width: 40%;
   }
}
```

You can adjust the percentage values in this CSS to customize the width of each element more to your liking.

New [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/jbzbOz)

Comment: sorry, that's incorrect. I want it when the screen resized, I can change the background position to the right, not centered

Comment: i dont want to pull it left or right, the background image still fullscreen. when it is below 768 or smaller, as your demo image shown, i want the background only show the people with the phone (what shows on the right side of image), and the notebook is hidden,

Comment: somehow I figured it out. I did this .carousel-inner>.item{background-position: 100% 50% !important;} and it works like magic! but still, thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem fanny glad I could help.